# Error when i try to delete specific item from card React Native asyncstorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

When i try to delete item from card, it won't be removed. When I go to home and come back to card, the changes are not saved, and items that I already deleted comes back again to card.

This error shows up in the terminal

[image]

I don't why this error shows up .. any help is appreciable

Comment: Please also provide the code in React Native. The context provided seems not sufficient.

Comment: This error is most likely not related to the `asyncstorage` but caused by code (most likely) that "surrounds" it. You will need to provide the code that calls it, as well as the full stack trace. This stack tract does not actually show the point your code called whatever library.